# How to make mobile wallet with my own coin

Tags: blockchain, cryptocurrency, bitcoind

I am a novice in blockchain technology, and I am now working on building mobile wallet with existing coin system.
Desktop wallet is already working well, and I am responsible for building mobile wallet.
I can not make sure how can I build it, and where should I start from.

I compiled coin system in vps, and I tried to install Bitcore wallet service and use it for RESTful API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I encountered this issue in my previous project.
I just used the electrum server for managing mobile devices with its own private key.
You can customize it as you want for your own coin.